# How to Make a textView visible on a given condition in C# in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning unity and I want to know how to make a text-view visible on a given condition for 5 sec and then again make it invisible and keep it going on whenever that condition meets.

```
if (scoreCount >= COMBO_JEWEL_GAIN) 
            {
                //MaketextVisible for 5 sec;
               //MaketextInvisible;

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have declared a GameObject called `text`, you can use [Coroutines](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/coroutines)

```
if (scoreCount >= COMBO_JEWEL_GAIN)
{
    text.SetActive( true ) ;
    StartCoroutine( DelayAction( () =>
    {
        text.SetActive( false ) ;
    }, 5 ) ) ;
}

// ...

// Outside of the function above
private IEnumerator DelayAction( System.Action action, float delay )
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds( delay ) ;
    if( action != null )
        action() ;
}
```

Comment: What if i don't want to show like this and want to show +1 each time the condition meets.?

Comment: and Can i do the same for Images as well? like Image.SetActive? I tried but it's not working.

Comment: Without more details, I won't be able to help you. If you want to show `+1`, then, my solution should work.
If you want to use an image, you can use `SetActive` on the gameobject : `image.gameObject.SetActive( true / false ) ;`